# MySQL Trigger issues. Tried everything

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I posted this over at SeverFault, but a colleague suggested I post here, incase anyone thinks my problem is not related to server resources.

I have a table with a complex BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER, that makes changes to itself, and several other tables. I’ve noticed that when the table experiences frequent use, that the trigger doesn’t update properly. Some rows are missing information. I’ve narrowed it down to a Ram, Buffer or other resources problem, as a 5 minute break temporarily fixes the issue.

The problem is I can’t find what resource is the problem. TOP doesn’t appear to show the resources being stressed. I have no errors in the error logs besides (Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity), and I can’t find any additional information on what settings might need adjusting.

MySQL 8.0.30

The server is an AWS R6G.Large (2 cores and 16 gigs ram).

Here are my current settings:

```
innodb_page_size=32k
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 11000M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 10
innodb_log_file_size=1G
```

The triggers execute quickly, under ~250ms. Tables are indexed.

Any ideas?

Update:

I read that innodb_log_file_size might help, since my Trigger can be write heavy. I changes it to 4G and reduced my buffer_pool to 8000. It didn’t change anything.

Update 2:

I tried doubling my AWS GP3 drive iops and that didn’t help either.

Update 3:

I download MySQLTuner and I’ve been trying to find problem. Here was my first run. PS: ignore the run times, the server has been running for quite some time and has been restarted for changes to take affect. The error logs only show warnings about my page size being 32 rather default 16.

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 2.0.4
     * Jean-Marie Renouard <jmrenouard@gmail.com>
     * Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 8.0.30
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysqld.log (119K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is readable.
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 219 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 41 error(s).
[--] 152 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2022-07-28T21:05:20.329531Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 2) 2022-07-28T21:05:20.329486Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 3) 2022-07-28T17:03:33.847697Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 4) 2022-07-28T17:03:33.846972Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 5) 2022-07-28T16:54:04.555913Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 6) 2022-07-28T16:54:04.555842Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 7) 2022-07-27T14:21:07.246178Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 8) 2022-07-27T14:21:07.246135Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 9) 2022-07-27T14:18:08.902979Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 10) 2022-07-27T14:18:08.902930Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 61 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2022-07-28T17:01:39.957456Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 2) 2022-07-28T16:52:31.049297Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 3) 2022-07-27T14:21:06.211690Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 4) 2022-07-27T14:18:07.913163Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 5) 2022-07-27T14:17:50.632446Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 6) 2022-07-24T17:00:14.927870Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 7) 2022-07-03T18:18:17.447139Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 8) 2022-07-03T17:40:23.940731Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 9) 2022-06-28T15:31:12.372708Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 10) 2022-06-28T14:34:20.734776Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 132.9M (Tables: 49)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Views Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Triggers Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Routines Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to unsupported feature for MySQL 8
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 15h 6m 28s (4K q [0.083 qps], 134 conn, TX: 13M, RX: 482K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 94% / 6%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 15.5G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 21.0G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 11.3G global + 65.9M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 11.5G (73.84% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 21.0G (135.07% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/4K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (3/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/134)
[!!] Name resolution is active: a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection which can reduce performance
[--] Query cache has been removed since MySQL 8.0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 1K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 1K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 97% (3 created / 134 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 89% (12K hits / 13K requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (2000) is greater than number of tables (378)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (2/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (8 immediate / 8 locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 100.00% (14 Memory / 14 Total)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance_schema is activated.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] MyISAM Metrics are disabled since MySQL 8.0.
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 11.2G / 132.9M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (17.7777777777778%): 1.0G * 2 / 11.2G should be equal to 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 10
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 90 for 10 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.82% (795401 hits/ 796838 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 64.88% (1395 hits/ 2150 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 755 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine not available.
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Check warning line(s) in /var/log/mysqld.log file
    Check error line(s) in /var/log/mysqld.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Buffer Key MyISAM set to 0, no MyISAM table detected
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: 

Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    skip-name-resolve=1
    key_buffer_size=0
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=1G) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=11)
```

Then I updated my CNF with these changes:

```
innodb_page_size = 32k
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
key_buffer_size=0
skip-name-resolve=1
```

Tested my database, the problems remain. Then ran MySQLTuner again:

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 8.0.30
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysqld.log (3K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is readable.
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 8 warning(s).
[OK] /var/log/mysqld.log doesn't contain any error.
[--] 4 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2022-07-29T12:34:01.266661Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 2) 2022-07-29T12:34:01.266615Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 3) 2022-07-29T12:22:28.958824Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 4) 2022-07-29T12:22:28.958778Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 2 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2022-07-29T12:34:00.281719Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 2) 2022-07-29T12:22:27.895855Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 132.9M (Tables: 49)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Views Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Triggers Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Routines Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to unsupported feature for MySQL 8
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 2m 40s (3K q [18.863 qps], 73 conn, TX: 9M, RX: 357K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 94% / 6%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 15.5G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 17.8G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 8.0G global + 65.9M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 8.2G (52.94% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 17.8G (114.17% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/3K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (3/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/73)
[--] Query cache has been removed since MySQL 8.0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 1K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 1
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 697 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 95% (3 created / 73 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 86% (7K hits / 8K requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (2000) is greater than number of tables (378)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (2/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (4 immediate / 4 locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 100.00% (9 Memory / 9 Total)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance_schema is activated.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] MyISAM Metrics are disabled since MySQL 8.0.
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 8.0G / 132.9M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 1.0G * 2/8.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 64 for 8 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.92% (1917744 hits/ 1919233 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 68.55% (1138 hits/ 1660 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 522 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine not available.
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Check warning line(s) in /var/log/mysqld.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Buffer Key MyISAM set to 0, no MyISAM table detected
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    key_buffer_size=0
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-59 ~]$ sudo nano /etc/my.cnf
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-59 ~]$ sudo systemctl restart mysqld
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-59 ~]$ sudo perl mysqltuner.pl --user root --pass 'c%96>C>+7hYQMAzs2KHiiLMev'
 >>  MySQLTuner 2.0.4
     * Jean-Marie Renouard <jmrenouard@gmail.com>
     * Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 8.0.30
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysqld.log (5K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is readable.
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 12 warning(s).
[OK] /var/log/mysqld.log doesn't contain any error.
[--] 6 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2022-07-29T12:38:30.994528Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 2) 2022-07-29T12:38:30.994482Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 3) 2022-07-29T12:34:01.266661Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 4) 2022-07-29T12:34:01.266615Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 5) 2022-07-29T12:22:28.958824Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 6) 2022-07-29T12:22:28.958778Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 3 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 2022-07-29T12:38:29.986956Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 2) 2022-07-29T12:34:00.281719Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[--] 3) 2022-07-29T12:22:27.895855Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 132.9M (Tables: 49)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Views Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Triggers Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Routines Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to unsupported feature for MySQL 8
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 2m 34s (2K q [16.286 qps], 67 conn, TX: 7M, RX: 206K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 92% / 8%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 15.5G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 17.7G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 8.0G global + 65.9M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 8.2G (52.89% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 17.7G (114.12% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/2K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (3/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/67)
[--] Query cache has been removed since MySQL 8.0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 1K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 505 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 95% (3 created / 67 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 85% (6K hits / 7K requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (2000) is greater than number of tables (378)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (2/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (4 immediate / 4 locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 100.00% (9 Memory / 9 Total)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance_schema is activated.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] MyISAM Metrics are disabled since MySQL 8.0.
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 8.0G / 132.9M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 1.0G * 2/8.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 64 for 8 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.94% (2702848 hits/ 2704385 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 66.59% (1214 hits/ 1823 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 609 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine not available.
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Check warning line(s) in /var/log/mysqld.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
```

Comment: A) Is it likely that your use of  
    innodb_page_size=32k  
has been an influencing factor?    You may want to reconsider using the default here of 16K to avoid unknown areas of potential trouble.  
B) Why such a large innodb_buffer_pool_size when you have Less Than 1G of data and indexes?  4G and 4 instances would be plenty until major growth is experienced.
C) Posting TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (table with trigger); 
D) Posting source code for BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER might be helpful for us to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey Wilson. Thanks for the reply. A) What makes you think it could be the page size? And have you seen the page size have a similar effect before? B) If I do 4 and 4, what would you set log_file_size to? C/D) I would love to, but my business partner is against it at the moment.

Comment: April,         A) Never seen anyone using other than 16K in 8 years of tuning.  B) leave log_file_size alone until you have evidence it needs to be changed (due to higher activity).  C/D) mushrooms grow in the dark - unassisted.

Comment: Hey Wilson. Ok, I will build a test server with default page size and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Wilson. No luck. Built a new MySQL server from scratch, with the default page size and 4G/4 and the problem remains. Know anything about table_open_cache and table_open_cache_instances?

Comment: Yes, do know about toc and toci. Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Hey Wilson. My server, with the default page size, will have been running for 24hours tomorrow afternoon, so I will grab the data and links then. I appreciate the help.

Comment: `innodb_log_file_size` refers to a disk; don't decrease the buffer_pool.

Comment: I have not heard of anyone using innodb_page_size=32K.  Why did you decide to try it?

Comment: "server has been running for quite some time and has been restarted for changes to take affect" -- The issue is that the GLOBAL STATUS values are reset at restart.  Please wait for 24 hours, then provide what Wilson asked for.

Comment: Rick, are you suggesting I keep buffer_pool_instances or buffer_pool_size at my previous setting? Re 32K, it was suggested by an AWS engineer a few years ago for a previous design. I just kept it. Re 24 hours, understood. Thanks

Comment: Wilson, My MySQL server uses an AWS GP3 SSD with 3000 iops and 500MB of throughput. I ran the commands, and here is the output: https://justpaste.it/4yuh2  , thanks again. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @april_adams5 - `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should not be so big that it leads to swapping.  Swapping is very bad for performance.  Making it too small hurts performance unless the data is even smaller.  Since the data is only 132.9M, it will 11G versus 8G (or even 1G) will not matter -- same performance.

Comment: I guess we need to see the Trigger, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table involved.

Comment: Rick, there wasn’t anything in the data that could explain the issue? I will ask my business partner about sharing the trigger etc, but I really don’t think that’s the problem. Lets say my trigger fires each time a column is updated, and the column takes the values 1 and 2, and updates another table based on 1 or 2. I can toggle back and forth between the two options 30-50 times and it works correctly. Then it stops, and it doesn’t update the correct row or writes 0 instead of the correct value. If I wait, then try again, it starts working again.

Comment: Rick and Wilson, I was testing triggers and variations this morning and might have stumbled upon a clue. I opened a few separate sessions in DataGrip, and the problem occurs instantly. The sessions don’t even need to be sending data. For example, opening a few .sql trigger files with separate sessions causes the problem. Closing sessions and reopening sessions fixes it without delay. It does not take many sessions to cause the problem. Does that help us?

Comment: April,          Will try to complete my Workload Analysis within 24 hours.  Are you familar with Profiling?  If not, please get acquainted with this URL, we will need for you to use profiling soon for your trigger.  https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/query-profiling/

Comment: Wilson, sounds good. Thanks. Let me know if my post about Sessions helps or gives any ideas for me to test too.

Comment: You know now your TRIGGER problem is aggravated by multiple simultaneous connections and results in INSTANT failure.  Some day you will share your trigger code and SHOW CREATE TABLE (each-table);  so we can get on with determining cause of TRIGGER failure.

Comment: Wilson, if it’s not a resources problem, and indeed a problem with the trigger or table, what kind of mistakes cause these kind of issues? I’m struggling to understand why it works and then doesn’t. Would it just not function correctly at all if that were the case?

Comment: April, When could we schedule a Skype TALK?  My Skype ID is  wlhauck@aol.com  in Birmngham, AL  GMT -5 hrs (Central Time Zone).  Before lunch is usually best for me, top of any hour.  View profile for contact info, please.

Comment: April,  Could you post the URL(s) you used as your guide(s) to creating your trigger?  I would like to see the pattern you followed to get to your present state with your trigger.

Comment: Hey Wilson. Wow I really appreciate the offer, but I think I might have found something and you’ll likely know what the problem is. I can run a query in DataGrip of 500 update statements in a row. They are all different combinations of options to fire the trigger and update the other tables. It works correctly (took 5m41s). I then go to make one simple update, by directly changing a single value in the table, and it fails. Does that tell us where to look?

Comment: Wilson & Rick, Do triggers run the commands sequentially, in the order they are written in (top to bottom)?

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your AWS Pararmeter Group [mysqld] section

```
max_connect_errors=10  # from 100 to frustrate Hacker/Cracker breakin attempt
read_rnd_buffer_size=32K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 5
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON  # from OFF for error log list to allow corrective action.
```

Observations,
general_log_file and slow_query_log_file normally go to /log/ folder not /lib/ folders.  Lib's usually used for software, not logs.

View profile for contact info and get in touch for additional assistance, please.

Comment: Wilson, thanks for the suggestions. The server seems to perform the same with or without them and the issue remained. I did however adjust my trigger to use IF statements around a lot more functions and I haven’t had an issue yet, even after several hours of testing. Is there a limit to how much information / variables a trigger can handle? That’s the only thing I can think of as to why IF statements might have fixed the problem. Do triggers run sequentially (top to bottom)?

Comment: View profile for contact info and get in touch for additional assistance, please.