# MySQL query returns wrong results. DataGrip caching?

Tags: mysql, datagrip

A few weeks ago I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167738/mysql-trigger-issues-tried-everything/73200744?noredirect=1#comment129297275_73200744) about a problem I’ve been having with MySQL not returning the correct results when my queries / triggers run.

I think DataGrip is applying some kind of caching, or something that acts like caching, to my user variables.

Update:

Can anyone explain the results of these two queries?

Query 1: Returns the correct results when the conditions match. It returns nothing when the conditions don’t match, which is still correct.

Query 2: Returns the correct results inside the user variable when the conditions match, but when the conditions don’t match, it still returns the results from the previous match. Closing the connection, and opening a new one fixes the problem.

Why is @results1 not blank when the query doesn’t have a match?? It’s driving me nuts!

— Query1

```
SELECT results
from tb1 where
'1' = tb1.condition1 and
'2' = tb1.condition2;
```

— Query2

```
SELECT results
into
@results1
from tb1 where
'1' = tb1.condition1 and
'2' = tb1.condition2;

SELECT  @results1;
```

DataGrip video: https://filebin.net/i4b3azha59ckt3gh

Comment: Do you have a query to reproduce? And what version of DataGrip is it?

Comment: DataGrip 2022.2, Build #DB-222.3345.83… I can try to produce an example, but for now I updated my post with a very simple example.

Comment: Moscas, sorry for the delay. Was hard to create an example in a fiddle but here is the simplest version that’s reproducible. If I run this as is in DataGrip, it returns the correct result. If I then change ‘1’ to ‘’ , and run it again, it returns the original results. In the fiddle, if I change the condition to ‘’ then it returns blank as it should. It’s not a perfect example, so hope it helps. Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=388135f3505b6d70d2e08cfde92008db

Comment: Sorry, your example has some generic things so I cannot reproduce it. Can you show the real (not)working query?

Comment: Moscas, What do you mean by generic things? Not sure if a video helps: https://imgur.com/a/UolIQmo .. Unfortunately I can’t post the actual query.

Comment: Sorry my eyes hurt when I try to detect what is written in that video

Comment: Moscas, sorry, imgur reduced the quality. How about: https://filebin.net/i4b3azha59ckt3gh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the way MySQL works with SQL parameters wihtin the same session. So, the second result set is null (empty result set) and MySQL doesn't rewrite it's value.

For proper work you need to reinitialize SQL variables, e.g. by setting them to `null` or by closing sessions explicitly.

Here is the way I did it:

```
set @results1 = null;
set @results2 = null;
```

[image]